# Backup custom table

Tags: backup

In a WordPress site, I have some custom tables *with the correct WordPress prefix*, created with/for a plugin.

Does standard export function (XML) also save those custom tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not, it will only export all of your posts, pages, comments, custom fields, terms, navigation menus, and custom posts.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen